# POST Request with CloseableHttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to create an HTTP POST request from a simple Java Project.

I need to keep session and cookies through two requests, so I opted for the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html).

The code compiles with no errors and runs, but it returns a zero-length content and I can't understand why.

```
public class Test {

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    private static final String FORM_URLENCODED = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            BasicHttpContext httpCtx = new BasicHttpContext();
            CookieStore store = new BasicCookieStore();
            httpCtx.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, store);

            String url = "http://myhost:port/app/";
            String body = "my body string";

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, FORM_URLENCODED);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body);

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpCtx);
            HttpEntity respentity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("respentity: " + respentity);

            System.out.println("EntityUtils.toString(respentity): " + EntityUtils.toString(respentity));

            EntityUtils.consume(respentity);

            System.out.println("respentity: " + respentity);
            System.out.println("EntityUtils.toString(respentity): " + EntityUtils.toString(respentity));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The result is:

```
respentity: [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]
EntityUtils.toString(respentity): 
respentity: [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]
EntityUtils.toString(respentity):
```

**Updated:** I found out the response status is *302 (Found)*, when I do the same request from Postman it's *200 (OK)*.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, only `GET` requests resulting in a redirect are automatically followed. If a `POST` requests is answered with either `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` or with `302 Found`, the redirect is not automatically followed.

This is specified by the HTTP RFC 2616:

> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

With *HttpClient 4.2 (or higher)*, we can set the *Redirect Strategy* to [LaxRedirectStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.html), this strategy relaxes restrictions on automatic redirection of POST methods imposed by the HTTP specification.

So you can create the `CloseableHttpClient` instance with a method like the follow:

```
private CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient() {
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    return builder.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
}
```

And use it to manage the POST request.